# Java API for FileSystem changes?

Tags: java, api, filesystems, jnotify

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java detect changes in filesystem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3387634/java-detect-changes-in-filesystem)

Can anyone suggest a Java API for tracking events in FileSystem? I found one - JNotify, but it doesn't support 64-bit systems.

Also, the new java.nio.* library is very new to use in a deployment level application, as many JREs don't really support it yet.

One alternative is to poll the FS for changes, which I am sure many do, but my gut feeling says that it's going to be very resource intensive.

Comment: You are right about it being resource intensive which is why the WatchService was added to Java 7. http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html