# Returning files names in a directory in numeric order using Java

Tags: java

We have a situation where our directory has files with a prefix (say `MyFile`), followed by a number (e.g. MyFile1, MyFile2, MyFile3, …).  We would like to return the list of filenames in the directory, but in numeric order.  For example MyFile1, MyFile2, MyFile3, … , MyFile9, MyFile10, MyFile11, MyFile12 etc.).

The Java `File` class `list()` method returns the list of filenames but in lexicographic order (MyFile1, MyFile10, MyFile11, MyFile12, MyFile2, MyFile3…. , MyFile9 etc.).  Is there an API call that would return the filenames in the order we want?

---

**Addendum**
A slight variant of the solution suggested in [Java File.list() consistent order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6539583) has worked for me.  I have created a new method called `generateConsistentOrder`.  The code is as follows:

```
protected void generateConsistentOrder(String[] files, String prefixToDrop) {
        Arrays.sort(
                files,
                new Comparator<String>() {
                    public int compare(String a, String b) {
                        Integer retVal = null;
                        try {
                            Integer intA = Integer.parseInt(a.substring(a.indexOf(prefixToDrop)+prefixToDrop.length()));
                            Integer intB = Integer.parseInt(b.substring(b.indexOf(prefixToDrop)+prefixToDrop.length()));
                            retVal = intA.compareTo(intB);
                        }
                        catch (Exception e) {
                            retVal = a.compareTo(b);
                        }

                        return retVal;
                    }
                });
    }
```

Comment: does this help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7199929/11876612 ?

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is to use the `Files#list` method that comes from the `java.nio` package. With that on hand, you are going to end up with a stream of `Path` objects, on to which could apply a `Comparator` that will sort them using `Path#getFileName`.

With than in place you need to have an implemntation of the `Comparator` interface in place that will scrape the number from the given file path and compare the value against some other. A simple example is this:

```java
public class PathComparator implements Comparator<Path> {

    private static final Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile("\\d+");

    @Override
    public int compare(Path o1, Path o2) {
        var path1Matcher = PATTERN.matcher(o1.getFileName().toString());
        var path2Matcher = PATTERN.matcher(o2.getFileName().toString());
        Integer file1 = 0;
        Integer file2 = 0;
        if (path1Matcher.find()) {
            file1 = Integer.valueOf(path1Matcher.group());
        }

        if (path2Matcher.find()) {
            file2 = Integer.valueOf(path2Matcher.group());
        }
        return file1.compareTo(file2);
    }

}
```

Bringing it all together would then look like this:

```java
public static List<Path> listOrdered(String path) {
    try (var fileStream = Files.list(Paths.get(path))) {
        return fileStream
            .sorted(new PathComparator())
            .toList();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return Collections.emptyList();
}
```

Note I am using Java 16 for this example, but you can easily modify it to work with older Java version.

Comment: `Path.compareTo()` is platform-dependent, and it most probably sorts strings lexicographically. You need to write a custom comparator or use some utility function.

Comment: @AlexShesterov you are absolutely right and it seems I misread the question.