# reading the value of text file when it gets updated

Tags: java

I am trying to read the contents of a text file and write to another file. The thing is I want to read the file every 1sec. Here is what I have tried.

```
void setData() {
      System.out.println("inside setdata");
      String line = null;
      String file = "E:/sss.txt";
      FileInputStream fis = null;
      String text = null;
      try{
             ....

     while(true) {

       byte bt[] = new byte[(int) file.length()];

        fis.read(bt);
        text = new String(bt);
        System.out.println( text);
        fis.close();  
        line = text + line;
        while(text != null) {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        System.out.println(line);
        }     
      }
     }catch (Exception e){

            }

    }
```

Where am I wrong here?

What Iget is

```
inside setdata
inside try
http://www.
http://www.null
http://www.null
http://www.null
```

going on and on 
  Thanks in advance

Comment: what wrong behavior are you encountering?

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/494869/file-changed-listener-in-java) for other options

Answer (score 0):

You might have more luck using my async DataFetcher class:

http://tus.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/tus/tjacobs/io/DataFetcher.java?view=log

get the file input stream, feed that to a DataFetcher, run it in a thread, and add a FetcherListener to the DataFetcher