# JAVA read excel file

Tags: java, excel, jboss

I have a program (deployed to JBOSS 5) that reads parameters from excel file.

The User may add/remove parameters from the excel file. However the code does not recognize the modified excel file until jboss restarts.

Should I make a conf. change or should I change something in the code to get the parameter changes in my code?

```
File file = new File(configurationFileName);
Workbook workbook;
try {
    workbook = Workbook.getWorkbook(file);

    Sheet sheet =
        workbook.getSheet(Constants.CONFIGURATION_SHEET_TAX_RATES);
    if (sheet != null) {
        for (int columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < sheet.getColumns();
             columnIndex++) {
            String headerValue =
                getCellContents(sheet, columnIndex, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should use [*Apache-poi*](http://poi.apache.org/download.html) Java API. It's very handy for Microsoft Office Tools. As you're dealing with Excel, It can be used for both XLS and XLSX.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use FileWatchDog

Answer (score 0):

Check this answer: [File changed listener in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/494869/file-changed-listener-in-java)

A good way is to use DefaultFileMonitor from Apache Commons VFS:
http://commons.apache.org/vfs/apidocs/org/apache/commons/vfs2/impl/DefaultFileMonitor.html

And an example on using that:
http://tunatore.wordpress.com/category/apache-commons-vfs/