# Input Output using java

Tags: java, io, nio

If we open a file with my java application and open the same file with another application
and made some changes. The java application I made, should know it immedeately that this file
is changed by some external application, and prompt the user to load the fresh content.
How to do it using java?

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/494869/file-changed-listener-in-java

Answer (score 2):

This question is asked before here

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5379458/java-filewatcher

read this http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html

Answer (score 1):

You can make check in this handler:

```
frame.addWindowFocusListener(new WindowAdapter() {
    public void windowGainedFocus(WindowEvent e) {
        // TODO: read file again and compare with previous 
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to have thread that polls for file information. See this question [File changed listener in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/494869/file-changed-listener-in-java).