# How to read a live file - that is being writen by another writer thread

Tags: java, java-io

I want to read a (log file being written continuously by an app)

Currently I have temp solution using RandomAccessFile (read mode)

Is there any other solution to this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

Java 7 has new API that allows listening to the file system events: http://java.dzone.com/news/how-watch-file-system-changes

If you are stuck with previous version of java use poling as described here: [File changed listener in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/494869/file-changed-listener-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

You probably could use `FileInputStream` to read this file.  The fact that another process/thread is writing to it should not be a problem, especially if it only appends data to the file.