# Infinite loop thread reading from pipe enters a timed_waiting

Tags: java, multithreading, named-pipes

I need a thread running in the background reading from a pipe but the loop suddenly stops & when I display the thread state I find it in TIMED_WAITING how to prevent it from such a behavior,below the code running within the thread, Thanks in advance.

```
BufferedReader in = null;

while (started) {

  String xml = "";
  // char [] buf=new char[250];
  try {
    in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(pipeName));
    while (!in.ready()) {
    }

    // in.read(buf,0,buf.length);
    xml = in.readLine();
    // in.close();

  } catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("error:" + e.getMessage());

    continue;
  }

  if (xml != null && !xml.equals("")) {

    System.out.println("recieved: " + xml);
  }
}
```

**Edit:**
After using @thomas's link the program runs fine with the print but when I try to parse pr do some functions on the string the data read becomes un stable & incomplete

Comment: Get rid of this: `while(!in.ready()){}`

Comment: @GregKopff now it stops after longer period

Comment: what about the wait-notify pattern? So you don't have an infinite loop in your code.

Comment: @Thomas I am trying to build some sort of a circuit simulator which has the UI written in java & both the circuit & micro controller simulator are built in C, So when I start simulating code I need the java UI to continously read the values from the circuit simulator; That's why I need the infinite loop of course it will get to be stopped

Comment: @AbdoSalem : Ahh okay that indeed is something different. I assume the C code writes into a file and you want a live update of the file in java. Maybe this is a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14799945/how-to-read-a-live-file-that-is-being-writen-by-another-writer-thread

Comment: @Thomas Thanks, I was really searching for something like this, Sadly it didn't work also the same problem it stops detecting changes after a little while although there is data in the pipe, Trying to debug hoping it will work, Thx after all

Comment: @AbdoSalem Are you able to change the C code? Maybe you could switch to socket communication.

Comment: @Thomas yes I am able, It just worked when I removed the xml parsing from the java code & replaced it by just some simple string manipulation

Comment: @AbdoSalem would you mind creating an answer? I'm interested, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry @thomas for the delay, 
When I first asked the question I had two C programs and 1 java,
the first C program write in the pipe then unlinks it while the other one writes many times if it unlinks the pipe the thread in java stops after an interval of time, but if it doesn't unlink the data  us recieved & printed well according to the edit assumed by @GregKopff but when I add xml parsing to the data written by the second program the data arrives corrupted & missing, I assumed that the xml parsing takes too much time, so I changed the format of the data sent by just adding a separator, I know it is not considered a solution but it worked for me, Sorry again for the delay If you want a version of the  please ask, I hope it's helpful