# Intellij: maven install on pom changes

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

Can Intellij IDE automatically do a `mvn install` on pom changes?

I have a multi-module maven project, and currently, when I make changes to the pom file, I have to do `mvn install` manually.

I know that I can execute Lifecycle commands automatically by setting the following options, but these are not what I wanted.
[image: Lifecycle Hooks]

Comment: Spring boot dev-tools automatically restarts whenever files on the classpath change.

Answer (score 1):

There is a tool called 'filewatcher'. Find more info in jetbrains docs: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-file-watchers.html?section=Windows%20or%20Linux

Comment: Thanks that works perfectly fine! Unfortunately only available in the ultimate edition.

Comment: You can also look for more 'manual' options, such as: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/494869/file-changed-listener-in-java
especially 'André' response.